# rake db:create using PostgreSQL ---- fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

New to all this so please be patient. Basically I was trying to follow [this](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.04) to get Rails set up on my Linux Lite machine. After installing PostgreSQL I went ahead to create a database role, as per the tutorial instructions, like this

```
sudo -u postgres createuser tjjjwxzq -s
```

But I didn't follow up with creating a password with this role, as the tutorial made it seem like it was an optional thing. I specified the development environment username in my `database.yml` file:

```
development:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_development

  # The specified database role being used to connect to postgres.
  # To create additional roles in postgres see `$ createuser --help`.
  # When left blank, postgres will use the default role. This is
  # the same name as the operating system user that initialized the database.
  username: tjjjwxzq

  # The password associated with the postgres role (username).
  #password:

  # Connect on a TCP socket. Omitted by default since the client uses a
  # domain socket that doesn't need configuration. Windows does not have
  # domain sockets, so uncomment these lines.
  #host: localhost
```

(**Edit:** I uncommented `host:localhost`)

I also changed the `pg_hba.conf` file to authenticate with the role I created:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# settings for tjjjwxzq user
local   all             tjjjwxzq                                     trust

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

As you can see I set the authentication method for the `tjjjwxzq` user to `trust`, because I didn't create a password and I don't want to have to supply one. But when I run, in my Rails project directory

```
rake db:create
```

I get:

```
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
...
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "database"=>"myapp_test"}
```

I am completely new to PostgreSQL and Rails, and I have been googling around for a solution for hours now. Changing the `pg_hba.conf` file seemed promising, but it hasn't worked for me. I suspect I could get pass this by specifying a password for the `tjjjwxzq` role I created, but I want to understand why my setup now is not working. Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Okay, I've realized I've made a dumb mistake. `rake db:create` does work for creating `myapp_development` (the specified development database) I've checked the log file, and the latest logs were:

```
2015-04-01 07:04:28 SGT [2342-1] tjjjwxzq@postgres ERROR:  database "myapp_development" already exists
2015-04-01 07:04:28 SGT [2342-2] tjjjwxzq@postgres STATEMENT:  CREATE DATABASE "myapp_development" ENCODING = 'unicode'
```

Now I realize that in the output for `rake db:create`, the last line displays

```
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "database"=>"myapp_test"}
```

So the problem was actually with my test database, and looking at my `database.yml` file, I see:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: 5

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_test
```

So there is no `username` field. Thanks for your help so far, but now my questions would be: 1) is it okay for `myapp_test` to not be created successfully, or should I set its user to `tjjjwxzq` as well? And 2) where can a newb like me read up more about this to get a better understanding (but nothing overwhelmingly technical, for now) of what is going on and the need for the `development`, `test` and `production` configs and environments? Rails docs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't like this.

```
sudo -u postgres createuser tjjjwxzq -s
```

There's no reason to make that user a superuser (`-s`) for the whole cluster. Just allow that user to create databases.

```
sudo -u postgres createuser tjjjwxzq --createdb
```

Change your config/database.yml to use sockets. Comment out the `host: localhost` line. (I'm assuming you're not running under Windows.)

```
  # Connect on a TCP socket. Omitted by default since the client uses a
  # domain socket that doesn't need configuration. Windows does not have
  # domain sockets, so uncomment these lines.
  # host: localhost
```

You had set up your pg_hba.conf to trust connections on sockets; uncommenting this line makes Rails try to connect using tcp instead of sockets.

This *should* work now.

```
$ bin/rake db:create
```

Comment: ah ok. But how do I change the role privileges after I've already created `tjjjwxzq` as superuser? Will running `sudo -u postgres createuser tjjjwxzq --createdb` simply overwrite the previous privileges? Also, if I run `rake db:create` before changing user privileges, I should be able to change the privileges afterwards without affecting anything right?

Comment: As the user "postgres" (probably the only other superuser you have), you can execute the SQL statement `alter role tjjjwxzq nosuperuser createdb;`. You should be able to change *these* privileges without affecting anything else, although that's not true in the most general case. (The Rails user in config/database.yml needs to have createdb privileges, but doesn't need superuser privileges.)

Comment: ok, I changed the privileges of `tjjjwxzq` and altered the `database.yml` file. But when I ran `rake db:create` still no joy. The error is  the same `fe_sendauth: no password supplied`. Any ideas?

Comment: The connection adapter is matching the wrong rule (wrong line) in pg_hba.conf. Look at the PostgreSQL log file to see which line it *did* match; might need to specify the socket directory. Which operating system?